# How to use linkerd as a router to another service/IP

Tags: docker, linkerd

I'm trying to use Linkerd as a router to another service running on the same/different IP but on another port.
HTTP Request ---> Linkerd listening on 4142 ------> Service listening on 4041

I tried multiple combinations on dtab section of the configuration file but none have worked.

Linked config file

```
routers:
- protocol: http
  dtab: /svc => /$/inet/127.1/9990;
  servers:
  - port: 8080
    ip: 0.0.0.0
    maxConcurrentRequests: 250
  identifier:
    kind: io.l5d.header
    header: google
- protocol: http
  label: test-http
  dtab: |
    /svc => /#/127.0.0.1/4041;
  servers:
  - port: 4142
    ip: 0.0.0.0
```

I'm getting:

```
Unable to route request!

service name: /svc/localhost:4142
dtab:

base dtab:
  /svc => /127.0.0.1/4041
override dtab:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use static addresses in dtabs, you have to specify the "inet" namer:

```
routers:
- protocol: http
  label: test-http
  dtab: |
    /svc => /$/inet/127.0.0.1/4041;
  servers:
  - port: 4142
    ip: 0.0.0.0
```

See [here](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Names.html) for more info how to use dtabs.